# Spawn random sprites and have the fly across screen. | Swift

Tags: swift, random, sprite

I want to spawn sprites in random spots *outside* of the view. Then I want each sprite to move towards the center of the screen and out the other side.

Anyone have a solution? I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Here's my code:

[image]

Comment: You can see the starship example which is created each time your create a new spritekit project to acomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize it was as simple as spawning the sprites at a certain point, and then telling them to move to another point. I've learned so much in the two days since I asked this question.